# ITLibrary: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 7011.)

Tags: objective-c, macos, itunes, ituneslibrary, osstatus

Usually, initializing `ITLibrary` works like a charm.

But when calling

```
NSError *error = nil;
ITLibrary *library = [ITLibrary libraryWithAPIVersion:"@1.0" error:&error];
```

on a customer's machine, I get a `The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 7011.)` error message.

Does anybody know what that means and how to fix it?

This is on macOS 10.15.7, after using Migration Assistant, i.e. moving from an older machine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was eventually resolved.

Since it is very unlikely that one comes up with the solution, I'm going to post it here:

> There was a different issue where an iPhone wasn’t connecting to Finder. A level 2 tech Apple support person suggested to open the TV app and the Music app. Opening both apps somehow fixed both problems.